# raid10: can't read superblock

Tags: 14.04, raid

Up until a few minutes ago I had a functioning raid 10 device (`/dev/md0`) consisting of 4 x 3TB disks.

My operating system (headless ubuntu server 14.04.1 lts) is mounted on a 120GB SSD seperate from the raid.

I was reading about noatime and that it is good for SSDs (i am new to ssds) so I edited `/etc/fstab` to add `noatime` to my ssd entry.

I then tried rebooting the headless server and it would hang during boot because it could not mount my raid `/dev/md0` under `/mnt/raiddisk:`

```
The disk drive for /mnt/raiddisk is not ready yet or not present.
Continue to wait, or press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.
```

Now I have booted by skipping the mounting of the raid device.

`cat /proc/mdstat` says:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : inactive sdd1[3](S) sdc1[2](S) sdb1[1](S)
8790402048 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

There is one disk missing in the above list, there should be also sde

Trying to mount manually using `sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raiddisk` gives the following output:

```
mount: /dev/md0: can't read superblock
```

After some reading I tried:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
```

And got this message:

```
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/md0 is already in use.
```

So I stopped `/dev/md0` and tried again and this time it seems to have worked:

```
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 4 drives.
```

Now `cat /proc/mdstat` gives:

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid10 sda1[0] sdd1[3] sdc1[2] sdb1[1]
5860267008 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

I was now able to mount it at `/mnt/raiddisk`.

Upon trying to restart it again hangs during boot because it cannot mount the raid device.

Not sure what else to test/check as I am a raid newbie.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it.

Upon inspecting the output of `sudo parted -l` and `cat /proc/mdstat` as well as looking in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` I noticed that the device labels for the harddisks seem to have changed after I tried adding `noatime` in `/etc/fstab`.

My ssd used to have the label `/dev/sda` this then changed to `/dev/sde`

So md could not auto assemble the raid array upon boot because it could not add `/dev/sde` to the raid as this was now the ssd for the boot partition.

Upon updating `mdadm.conf` and adding the updated disk labels and then running `update-initramfs -u` I was able to reboot normally and the raid array is assembled and mounted.

I have no idea why simply adding `noatime` to my ssd entry in `/etc/fstab` did this.

I have since removed `noatime` from my `/etc/fstab` as I am terrified of it happening again.

Comment: I'd very much like to see if that happened again. If yes, can you add more details to the answer?